# Capital Gains on Stock Sold in Order to Sell House

Tags: united-states, taxes, mortgage, capital-gain

I'm currently underwater on my mortgage. If I liquidated part of my mutual fund holding in order to pay the difference between the sale price of the house and what is owed, does the standard capital gains rate apply?

Is there some kind of strategy involved to avoid taking too big a hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tax is on the sale of the investment, it doesn't really matter why you sell it. So yes, the standard tax rates would apply. You might want to get the bank to "forgive" you the loan, and then it won't be taxable, but that's only until the end of the year IIRC (unless the law changes). This would have a toll on your credit score though (assuming you're in the US of course).

Comment: Actually, debt forgiveness in the US counts as income. if the mortgage lender forgives all or part of a loan, and it's not a part of a federal loan modification program that exempts the adjustment, the bank will file a 1099 for the amount forgiven (it saves them taxes) which then adds to your taxable income.

Comment: @KeithS http://www.irs.gov/individuals/article/0,,id=179414,00.html

Comment: OK, so all mortgages are exempt.

Answer (score 1):

Some retirement funds can be used to pay for the purchase of a first house. This can be done by a loan from the 401K or by pulling the money out of the account. Unfortunately you are not buying a house, you are selling a house.

One way to reduce your taxes on the sale of part of your investments is to specify only shares that will be sold at a loss. So any shares of companies/funds that haven't fully recovered to their pre-crash peak can be specified as the ones you want to sell.

The losses are then balanced against the winners you sell in order to reduce the taxable amount. If you only sell losers, there are limitations on the amount of losses you can claim in any one year, but excess losses are rolled over into the following years.

By specifying only specific shares you can also make sure that shares with gains are shares that qualify at the long term rates.

Keep in mind that the sales of a large amount of shares for gains can impact your ability to qualify for some deductions and credits.